# Yii2 dropDownList get selected value

Tags: drop-down-menu, yii2, active-form

I have dropDownList in my view ( data from db) :

```
use yii\widgets\ActiveForm;
\app\assets\HelloAsset::register($this);
$form = ActiveForm::begin();
$users=\app\models\User::find()->all();
$items=\yii\helpers\ArrayHelper::map($users,'id','username');
echo $form->field($model, 'username')->dropDownList($items);
echo \yii\bootstrap\Html::submitButton('Send');
ActiveForm::end();
```

I want to get data from 'username' in my controller:

```
 $model=new Data();
    if ($model->load(\Yii::$app->request->post())){
        echo 'it is status:'.$model->username;
    }else {
        return $this->render('simple', ['model' => $model]);
    }
```

But data is null.
How I must get data in right?
Please, help me solve this problem.

Comment: I solve my problem: in my model User I forgot write rules() function